# Check if two out of 5 consecutive values are larger than x

Tags: r

I have a column with values and want to check if the sum of 5 consecutive values (within a certain range - row 259 to row 272) is > 10 and if at least two out of the 5 values are > 3

This is what I used to come up with the sum of 5 consecutive values. It divides my range into twelve blocks and check each block individually.

```
data <- read.table("....csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)
interval <- 5
start <- 259
end <- 272
block<-sapply(start:(end-interval+1),function(x){sum(data[x:(x+interval-1)])})
```

Now I check if the value of the block is > 10

```
if ( block [[1]]> 10 ) {
  print(paste("block to fulfill the condition is block", 1))
} else if ( block [[2]]> 10 ) {
  print(paste("block to fulfill the condition is block", 2))
....
```

How can I include the condition "two out of 5 values from a block have to be > 3" into my if-clause?

Comment: What would be your expected output? Those 5 values?

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: @RonakShah My expected output will be the number of the block where the conditions (sum of all 5 values within the block > 10 and at least 2 out of 5 values from the block > 3) are met for the first time

Answer (score 2):

To make it as reproducible example, I tried it on `mtcars` dataset.

Row 259 to 272 has been changed to 20 to 30 only for the `gear` column where the sum is greater than 20 and there are at least 2 out of 5 values having value greater than 3.

```
library(zoo)
subvec = mtcars[20:30, "gear"]
subvec
#[1] 4 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 5 5 5
idx <- which(rollsum(subvec, 5) > 20 & rollapply(subvec, 5, 
                                           function(x) sum(x > 3)) >= 2)[1]
idx
# [1] 6
subvec[idx:(idx+4)]
#[1] 3 4 5 5 5
```

So I think this should work on your dataset,

```
library(zoo)
subvec = data[259:272, "column"]
idx <- which(rollsum(subvec, 5) > 10 & rollapply(subvec,5, 
                                              function(x) sum(x > 3)) >= 2)[1]
subvec[idx:(idx+4)]
```

As @G.Grothendieck mentioned we can further simplify the code. Instead of using `rollapply` we can use `rollsum` on boolean vectors and then sum the ones which are `TRUE` like

```
idx <- which(rollsum(subvec, 5) > 10 & rollsum(subvec > 3, 5) >= 2)[1]
```

Comment: The `rollapply(...)` could be simplified to `rollsum(subvec > 3, 5)`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck well, that's a nice trick. Didn't think of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Having data:

```
set.seed(1453)
x = sample(-3:7, 13, TRUE)
n = 5
x
# [1]  4  1  6 -1  2  3  5  0  1  4  1  5  5
```

one approach is:

```
ex = embed(x, n)
(rowSums(ex) > 10) & (rowSums(ex > 3) >= 2)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

To avoid re-calculating same additions, we could use `cumsum`:

```
cs1 = cumsum(x)
cond1 = cs1[n:length(x)] - c(0, cs1[1:(length(x) - n)]) > 10

cs2 = cumsum(x > 3)
cond2 = cs2[n:length(x)] - c(0, cs2[1:(length(x) - n)]) >= 2

cond1 & cond2
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

So I am not quite sure if this is what you want. But here is a function to check for two condition, given a `column`, `start_row`, and `end_row`,

```
finder = function(column,start_row,end_row,threshold_1 = 10){
  for(i in start_row:end_row){
    if(sum(column[i:(i+4)])> threshold_1){
      if(sum(column[i:(i+4)]>3)>=2){
        print(paste("sum of row",i,"and its 4 consecutive values is greater than", threshold_1))
        print("And at least two out of the 5 values are greater than 3")
        return("END")
      }}}}
```

This is quite messy, but mostly due to the print messages.
And this is what you get:

```
set.seed(123)
col = sample(1:5, 300, T)
finder(col,259,279)

[1] "sum of row 269 and its 4 consecutive values is greater than 10"
[1] "And at least two out of the 5 values are greater than 3"
[1] "END"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rollapply` from `zoo` package and `intersect` as follows,

```
library(zoo)
ind1 <- which(rollapply(data$v1, 5, by = 1, sum) > 10)
ind2 <- which(rollapply(x, 5, by = 1, function(i)length(i[i>3]) >= 2))
intersect(ind1, ind2)
```